# Memory leak using fipy with trilinos

Tags: python, fipy, trilinos

I am currently trying to simulate a suspension flowing around a cylindrical obstacle using fipy. Because I'm using fine mesh and my equations are quite complicated, the simulations take quite a long time to converge. Which is why I want to run them in parallel. However, when I do that the program keeps using more and more memory, until Linux eventually kills it (after around 3 hours when I use 4 procesors).
What is more: trilinos increases memory usage even if I only use one processor. For example, when I run [this example](https://github.com/usnistgov/fipy/blob/master/examples/flow/stokesCavity.py) (changing no. of sweeps from 300 to 5,000 first):

**python stokesCavity.py --trilinos** -> memory usage goes from 638M to 958M in 10 minutes
**python stokesCavity.py --pysparse** -> memory usage goes from 616M to 635M in 10 minutes

I saw [here](https://www.mail-archive.com/fipy@nist.gov/msg03554.html) that somebody had reported a similar problem before, but I could not find the solution. Any help would be appreciated.

Some info: I am using Trilinos 12.12.1 (compiled against swig 3.0) and fipy 3.2.

Answer (score 0):

This is an [issue we have reported against PyTrilinos](https://github.com/trilinos/Trilinos/issues/2327)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I will try to install version 11.10.2 and see if the problem goes away.